# Error while connecting to MYSQL Server

Tags: php, mysql

Hostame: sql210.0fees.net
Username: *******
Password: *******

```
<?php

mysql_connect("sql210.0fees.net", "**", "***") or die("Fatal Error");


?>
```

is the code im using..

I get the following error while trying to connect to mysql host..

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connecti (trying to connect via tcp://sql210.0fees.net:3306) in C:\xampp\htdocs\data.php on line 3

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is the question? The error is quite clear, it cannot connect as other side did not respond.

Comment: The question is why is it not connecting. Is it something to do with my computer/connection?

Comment: **WHY** would you just update your question and post your username/password? Do you WANT to get hacked?

Comment: No, I just need some assistance...

Comment: and the password i gave was not the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, you try to connect to your database ( on sql210.0fees.net) from your computer ( C:\xampp\htdocs\data.php ).  Usually hosting provider doesn't permit this kind of connection.

Look with hosting provider if you can directly connect to your database from your home.

Comment: where else can i connect to the database from then?

Comment: Most hosting providers *only* let you connect from your webserver (that they're hosting), not another server.

Comment: only from your website once on their server (on sql210.0fees.net).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from posting fake/real (doesn't matter) username and passwords, you need to check with your provider (or system admin) about remote access.

If it is blocked, you would always take the slightly more advanced route and TUNNEL your traffic over SSH using putty.

Putty will allow you to extend a port from the remote host to your local machine (so it looks like you have mysql port attached to your development server).

Some tutorials (search):

- http://www.it-iss.com/support/mysql-secure-client-connections/ssh-tunneling-and-mysql/
- http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/95269

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are trying to connect to a remote database from the configs files in your local system. Also, you might want to put a mysql_error() after the "Fatal Error" message.